# Google sign-in fail error_description:"Invalid Value"

Tags: android, jwt, google-signin

My steps are as follows:

1) I logged in the app via Google for the first time, and it succeeded. Then I got my token, however, which is only available for 1 hour(3600s). Thus within this 1-hour duration, logging out and logging in are both successful behaviors;

2) I logged out after this 1-hour duration, then I could not log in again, as the token is not available any more for this day.

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=xxx

```
error_description: "Invalid Value"
```

3) If I changed the time and date on my phone settings to the next day, I could log in successfully again. It is supposed that the token was refreshed as my phone settings changed.

Here is Google Sign-In for Android doc: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

Therefore, do you have any idea regarding this issue? How can we refresh the id_token manually? Or how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

i think that you might use the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken();but the doc say that the void is not useful,you should use the newest api

Comment: If you want to add some information, like a source reference link, to your answer, it is better to include it by editing the answer instead of commenting on it.